# Will the MySQLi function close() still be called after exit()?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following bit of code where I'm redirecting after an `INSERT` to a *MySQL* database.

```
if ($connect->query($dragon_sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "You've picked the dragon book!";
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connect->error;
}

$connect->close();
```

I've read on the manual page that `exit`

> Terminates execution of the script. Shutdown functions and object destructors will always be executed even if exit is called.

So is `close()` a shutdown function or object destructor? I can't really tell by reading the PHP manual page for it.

Comment: The docs say *"Open non-persistent MySQL connections and result sets are automatically **destroyed** when a PHP script finishes its execution. So, while explicitly closing open connections and freeing result sets is optional, doing so is recommended. This will immediately return resources to PHP and MySQL, which can improve performance."* Since the connection is an object `close()` is a destructor.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks! Completely answered my question

Comment: To answer the question in your title (*which doesn't match the question in your question*) `close()` is never called because the script execution exits immediately after the redirect.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't match the question in my question? I felt that by asking, "is `close()` a shutdown function or object destructor?", that would give me the answer to the question in my title. Why? Because if `close()` _is_ one of those two, then I know that it gets called after `exit` due to the quote that I cited. Thus, it answers the title question :]

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ It's all good!

Comment: If you think about it - PHP knows when you open a db connection  and can record that internally. So, when the script exits, it checks checks to see if the connection is still active (i.e. you didn't close it). It then closes it for you. PHP does a lot of 'housekeeping' :)

Comment: @RyanVincent I didn't know that! I'm pretty inexperienced so that was a helpful tip, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

`exit()` or `die()` simply stops executing the rest of the script.
so it's not a desctructor.
 it's more of a shutdown function

mysqli `close()` function closes the connection to the database .. even though it's said to be useless because the connection is already closed by the end of the script.

Comment: He was asking if `close()` was a destructor or a shutdown function, not `exit()`.